# How to prevent on-tap of an outer polymer element when tapping an inner element?

Tags: polymer

I have a polymer element with an inner polymer element like

```
<paper-material on-tap='outerTap'>
   <div>Large clickable content</div>
   <paper-button on-tap='buttonTap'/>
<paper-material/>
```

When clicking on the button I would like to just fire `buttonTap` and ignore `outerTap`.

As `event.preventDefault()` does not work with tap, how can I achieve this?

**Update**
in `buttonTap` this seems to work

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for !